# Upgrading Squeeze to Wheezy after LTS stopped

Tags: linux, debian

I've got a server running Squeeze 6.0.1 which I want to upgrade to Wheezy. Docs for wheezy state that I should bring squeeze up to the latest point release before upgrading to Wheezy. Is that still possible now that LTS has ended? My sources list points at the sqeeze stuff, but I just get a bunch of 404 errors when i run apt-get update

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze

My apt sources needed to be pointed at archive.debian.org rather than http.debian.net

Comment: Correct, if you need to get the latest version of a package for something that is no longer on the regular mirror network, you need to use archive.debian.org

Comment: Hmm, not actually sure this does everything I want. Redirecting to the archives allows me to download the package updates with apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, but apt-get dist-upgrade yields no results. How do I get it to upgrade to 6.10?

Comment: There is no 6.10 (this isn't Ubuntu :-) However, there is a 6.0.10, which you get if you apt-get upgrade from the most recent sources. If it says "no updates available," that means you were already running 6.0.10 and need not do anything further

Comment: Ah,  I've been misreading the version numbers the whole time! Thanks!